# using jquery to communicate with php in same page (if cookies are set)

Tags: php, jquery, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a **frame.php** page

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
// do some stuff
}else{
// login script
}
```

In a **jquery.frame.php** page

```
$("#infm_login_button").live("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "urltologinformacceptance",
        type:"POST",
        data: $("#login").serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        //do stuff
    });
    return false;

});
```

Now in the same **frame.php** how do I make jquery tell, oh user has been logged in, yes go forward and go into the `// do some stuff` section. However, I do not want the user to refresh the page. I want it to just change the content from `// login script` to `// do some stuff` without refreshing the page, only when the user is logged in. Is there a way to make jquery talk to that **frame.php** and `cookie`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: live is deprecated since jQuery 1.4 or something. Use .on() instead.

Secondly, you do not want to 'do' something when the ajax-call is done, but when it is a succes. What if there's a time out? Try this:

```
                $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'url.php',
            data: $("#login").serialize(),

            success : function(data){
                $(document).html(data);
            }


                });
```

This will print the output of you url.php to the entire document, sort of like include() in php.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Djerro Neth answers. Echo the output for the logged in user (menus, links, etc.)

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
 // do some stuff
      echo "Welcome back ".$_COOKIE['user']."!";
 }else{
 // login script
 }
```

and overwrite the div you have with your login form with new content returned from frame.php using jQuery.

```
 success : function(data)
           {
              $("#loginspace").html(data);
           }
```